# What is the purpose of BASH_ARGV0 in bash?

Tags: bash, variable

In the release for [Bash-5.0](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-01/msg00063.html) it is mentioned that they added

> BASH_ARGV0: a new variable that expands to $0 and sets $0 on assignment.

What is the purpose of this? When is this an improvement over just using `$0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The changelog says

```
    - BASH_ARGV0: new dynamic variable, returns $0 on reference and sets
      $0 on assignment.  From a suggestion from  Rocky Bernstein <rocky@gnu.org>
      a few years ago
```

Rocky Bernstein is, among other things, the initial author of [the BASH Debugger](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/). When debugging, it can be useful to be able to set `$0` to different values; this led to [this suggestion](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2008-09/msg00054.html), ten years ago, of a `set0` built-in which would allow just that. I think `BASH_ARGV0` is the equivalent in the form of a special variable rather than a built-in.

`$0` only allows you to read the value; before Bash 5, it could only be set when starting the shell. `BASH_ARGV0` allows you to write the value as well as read it. `0` isn’t a valid variable name for assignment purposes, and enabling `0=...` would have been rather more complex.

Comment: One might ask why the need for a new variable, instead of just assigning to `$0` directly. But since `0` is not a valid variable name, `0=value` is not recognized as an assignment, and changing that would be more involved (and backward-incompatible)